# What is the quickest way to solve this multivariate limit?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Suppose you were given the following multivariate limit, and you want to solve it as fast as possible under exam conditions:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,3)} \frac {|\sin(3x-y)|} {\sqrt{2(x-1)^2+5(y-3)^4}}.$$

How would you do it? Is there any intuitive way of telling whether or not the limit is likely/unlikely to exist give the “form” of the function? I’m asking as I wouldn’t have known whether to first try different paths of approach, or binding it away with the squeeze law, and each of the two methods often take some trial and error, ending up as time drains, especially if it ends up not working (and I may be led to think that I haven’t tried the right path, nor used the correct algebraic manipulation instead of realising that strategy doesn’t work).

---

Note: the above limit does not exist, i.e., take the paths of approach $x=1$, then $y=3$.

Comment: Let first $x=X+1$ and $y=Y+3$ and work $$\frac{\sin (3 X-Y)}{\sqrt{2 X^2+5 Y^4}}$$ around $(0,0)$

Comment: Now, try $Y=X$ to have $\sqrt 2$ and then $Y=2X$ to have $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. I forgot the asolute value in my first comment